# Font Search App

Tags: search-engine, font

I read about an webapp that you can point at an image that contains text and it will tell you what font was used to create it.

Unfortunately I can't remember what it was called ... does anyone have a link?

Comment: Funny, Googling your question title gives the answer on the first hit.

Comment: @Vortico well not exactly.. it gives _WhatTheFont for iPhone: Overview « MyFonts_ and if you don't have iPhone you wouldn't even click on it.. :)

Comment: True. It's not all bad. Maybe googling "Font Search App" in the future will return this exact page. Good for SEO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using [WhatTheFont](http://new.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/).