# Web app that "guess" the font of an image?

Tags: images, font

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Font Search App](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/5653/font-search-app)

Is there a web service that is able to "guess" the font of a text?

For example, I have an image shown below:

[image]

The text is "Type text or a website" and the text color is #666666. What may be the best guess of the font used?

As another example, I have an image shown below:

[image]

The text is "DESIGN PAINTING" and the text color is #343434. What may be the best guess of the font used?

Answer (score 4):

http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/ does what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The [Identifont](http://www.identifont.com/) site can help identify a font.

To let Identifont find the typeface you have to answer a set of questions questions to get the closest match in their huge database of typefaces.